# mFusedLocationClient return null (Case : Device offline with GPS on)

Tags: java, android, google-api, gps

I'm trying to add the new version of FusedLocationClient. I want to do it in a certain case, my phone is in offline mode, and GPS is On !

what I did ==>

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
```

.

```
 LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult); // why? this. is. retarded. Android.
                        Location currentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                        System.out.println("Loc => " + currentLocation.getLatitude());
                    }

                    ;
                };
mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
```

But I got a null result when I printed it. I don't really understand why. If someone can explain to me what's wrong, big thank's !

Comment: What is null? `locationResult`?

Comment: Yeap, when I try to print the latitude...

Comment: And now, onLocationResult() is never called :'( Wtf

Comment: If its not getting called then you dont have a GPS lock, since you are not on a network connection it cannot use AGPS to find your location and is relying solely on the GPS chip which is going to be very sporadic

Comment: But, well,  is it technically, possible to find the user's position with the device offline, GPS On, and indoor ?

Comment: it is possible yes but indoor GPS is extremely unlikely, you basically need a clear view of the sky with just your GPS. There is a reason wifi or bluetooth beacons are used indoors and not GPS